# Discord.js - mixing dynamic command handler with collectors/await message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm currently programming a Discord Bot to reply after being prompted a certain command. As the commands can be confusing, I was thinking about making it ask for questions, collect the replies from the user and then based on it, reply with the correct answer.

This is the code I have right now. I've tried to add collectors/await messages but I failed.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandName = fs.readdirSync('./commands');
const commandSmokes = fs.readdirSync('./smokes');
const commandMolotovs = fs.readdirSync('./molotovs');
const commandFlashbangs = fs.readdirSync('./flashbangs');

// Loads files under commands sub-folders
for (const folder of commandName) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}
// Loads files under smokes sub-folders
for (const folder of commandSmokes) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./smokes/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./smokes/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}
// Loads files under molotovs sub-folders
for (const folder of commandMolotovs) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./molotovs/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./molotovs/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}
// Loads files under flashbangs sub-folders
for (const folder of commandFlashbangs) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./flashbangs/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./flashbangs/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('Command not available.');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

And the commands:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'd2-smoke-xbox-tspawn',
aliases: ['dust-smoke-xbox-tspawn', 'dust2-smoke-xbox-tspawn', 'd2-smoke-xbox-spawn','dust2-smoke-xbox-spawn', 'dust-smoke-xbox-tspawn'],
description: 'Dust 2 - Xbox Smoke From T-Spawn',
execute(message) {
    message.channel.send('https://youtu.be/q91_mN1IUpw 64 tick | https://youtu.be/q91_mN1IUpw 128 tick');
}, 
};
```

As you can see, the commands need to be specific in order to make it work, instead of having a command for each sub-folder and then sorting what I want inside of it.
I was looking for something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHMgJ.png).

Is there any way to make it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use awaitMessages() again. For each prompt, you can do something like this:

```
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
let utility;
message.channel.send("What kind of utility are you looking for?")
.then(() => message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 }))
.then(collectedMessage => {
    utility = collectedMessage.content;
}
```

You can do this for each prompt you need.